# Web servers vs application servers, Open source database Security vs Enterprise Database security

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am working on creating a spec for a startup to create a financial broker check website. It involves storing information about financial advisers and payment details of the users (so obviously needs a lot of security). What kind of databases are best suited for the application. Is MySQL or its open source variations enough or is it better to go with Oracle Enterprise etc. Also any info about the usefulness of application servers over traditional web servers (cloud based or normal) in this scenario and the preferred scripting language (PHP, Ruby, Python) for secure web applications.

Comment: Languages and databases are rarely inherently insecure - it's what you do with them that counts: how are they exposed to the outer world, how is access to the machines hosting them managed, are you using an ORM versus handcrafting SQL etc

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of language, database, etc. has a relatively small impact on the security of your application.  The developer's understanding of how to write secure code and the developer's understanding of the features provided by their tools is far more important.  It is entirely possible to write a secure application on an open source LAMP stack.  It is entirely possible to write a secure application on a completely closed source stack.  It is also very easy to write insecure applications on any stack.

An enterprise database like Oracle will (depending on the edition, the options that are licensed, and the add-ons that are purchased) provide a host of security functions that may be useful.  You can transparently encrypt the data at rest, you can encrypt the data when it flows over the network to the app server, you can prevent the DBA from viewing sensitive data, you can audit the actions of the DBA and other users, etc.  But these sorts of things really only come into play when you've written a reasonably secure application to begin with.  It does you little good to encrypt all the data if your application is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and can be easily hacked to present all the decrypted data to the attacker, for example.